# C# Call the same function with different values at the same time

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a function that changes the text in a label for another one, showing the text transition effect. Imagine that I have 4 labels with texts, and I want to replace their texts with another different ones, showing the same effect but for the 4 labels at the same time, is there any way to do that? Call the same function with different values at the same time.

Thanks in >>

Comment: Why don't you just call the function for each label? Is there any noticeable delay? Using multithreading, as specified by your tag is definitely quite an overkill.

Comment: What sort of application is this?  If it's a WinForm app, it may be as simple as calling SuspendLayout(), processing, then calling ResumeLayout().  Without any code, it's hard to figure out what exactly you're asking here.

Comment: Im guessing that if its called "effect" its noticable for user. So if u would do it for all labels in squence it would be noticeable.

Comment: thanks for respond, indeed it is a WinForm app, and the effect is noticeable by the user, but that's the thing, I don't want to do it in sequence, I need it all at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using double-buffering to achieve this effect.  You update the labels, and then use double-buffering to show the completed form.  There are plenty of articles on enabling this for WinForms apps, and the concept is applicable to most UI platforms.

Windows UI (for WinForms at least) doesn't like to be updated from multiple threads, so I wouldn't bother trying to pursue that (unless you require a lot of background computation to get the new values)

Comment: Thanks holtavolt, I get the new values thru a StoredProc, using a DataReader, I have a struct, let's say Data.Info1, ..., Data.Info4, and a List of Data. And for instance I want to change the texts of the 4 labels (which corresponds to List[0]) for the List[1] showing the transition effect, if I understand you right, I won't see the effect, just the labels with the new values already changed.

Comment: OK - I missed the part about the transition effect and it's API.  A timer-based animation that let you update multiple controls animation would work here, but that would require that your transition effect API supports "single stepping" the animation.  What is the text transition effect you are using?

Comment: One I made, working with strings. Are there default animations that can be applied to the text of a label?

Comment: There are no default animations I'm aware of.  If you wrote a transition effect, you should be able to update your own API to accept a list of controls, their old values, and new values, and update each of them with a single animation "step" at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your function to change all labels at once. Something like this:

```
Foreach EffectStep
    Foreach Label
      do some job
```

Comment: Why downvote? If u dont like answer comment why ... . Its only pseudo code showing idea, not somthing that should be understood as compileable code

Comment: Yeah im used too much to using u instead of you, sry ;)